# WordPress start page doesn't show content anymore, only message from server hoster

Tags: wordpress

When I try to access the start page of my website (WordPress) I get a message from my server provider that this site will soon be available.

When I try to access a sub page, everything is fine. Before the problem I tried to change my URL structure. I changed the menu and gave the homepage another title. (no changes in files were made) I think I have undone my changes, but maybe not all of them, because the problem still occurs. I don't know where to search for the problem any more.

I have checked/tried:

- choose different theme
- options -> reading -> start page -> correct start page is selected, also tried to choose different pages
- deactivate caching
- changed the title from the start page back to the old title

What could be possible reasons that the start page is the only page which can't get viewed?

Comment: Maybe you should contact your server provider, ask him if he has done any changes in config lately.

Comment: @RDardelet I already did that, he said no changes were made. The rest of the site works just fine, but when attempting to access the homesite it shows the template of the server provider which is in root

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. There was an index.htm in root from the server provider. I'm not sure if it was there before but however, for some reason Wordpress gave the index.htm a higher weight than my index.php. I renamed the index.htm and everything worked perfect again :)